# Error with fstream library

Tags: c++, fstream

I simply want to open a file in writing only and put it in a variable there is the error :

```
Include/FileStream/FileStream.cpp: In function 'void log(std::__cxx11::string)': Include/FileStream/FileStream.cpp:26:5: error: request for member 'close' in 'log', which is of non-class type 'void(std::__cxx11::string) {aka void(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)}'  log.close;
     ^ Include/FileStream/FileStream.cpp: In function 'void firstName_read(bool)': Include/FileStream/FileStream.cpp:36:18: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
           return firstname;
                  ^ Include/FileStream/FileStream.cpp:42:18: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
           return firstname;
```

and there is the File that is making trouble :

```
#include "FileStream.h"
void log(string argument)
{
logFile.open ("log.txt", fstream::out | fstream::app);

logFile << argument;

log.close;
}

void firstName_read (bool boyOrGirl)
{

if (boyOrGirl == true)
     {
          firstname.open("Name/FirstName_Male.txt", fstream::in);

          firstname.close;
          return firstname;
     }
else
     {
          firstname.open("Name/FirstName_Female.txt", fstream::in);
          firstname.close;
          return firstname;

     }
}
```

Thank you... if you want all the file i have the project hosted on github :

https://github.com/calmunicorn/virtualsociety

Comment: Where is `logFile` declared?

Comment: Where is `firstname` declared?

Comment: Why is `firstname` trivially opened and closed without doing anything?

Comment: Try reading the error messages, they tell you what's wrong. Then fix it.

Comment: logfile and firstname are declared in a header file

Answer (score 4):

`close` is not a `ifstream` attribute, it's a method. Use `firstname.close()` to call the function rather than `firstname.close`.

Additionaly, a `void` function cannot return a value and also `firstname`....`log.close` should also be `logFile.close()`....there are actually tones of errors in your code.

You may want to start with a simplier piece of code, make it work, and later extend it....

Comment: Also `log.close()`, whatever `log` is.

Comment: @erip : it's the surrounding function !

Comment: Ah, haha. Can't say that's intuitive, considering that's not real syntax (or semantics, for that matter!). :P

Answer (score 4):

In your function `log`, the file is named `logFile`. But you try `log.close`. That really confuses the compiler; you can't close a function ! Use `logfile.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

`void firstName_read( /*...*/`  is a function returning nothing aka `void`. If you want to return a `std::string`, define it as `std::string firstName_read( /*...*/`

Answer (score 0):

thank you all of you have helped me fixing the issue now i got some other issues but i will open a new post for that XD